# TFS2015 Limit the number of simultaneously running builds

Tags: tfs, teamcity, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In TeamCity there is the possibility to limit the concurrent builds per build definition. This means you can build multiple definitions at the same time, but if 1 definition is queued multiple times, it wil be executed 1 by 1.

**Limit the number of simultaneously running builds**

*Specify the number of builds of the same configuration that can run simultaneously on all agents. This option helps avoid the situation, when all of the agents are busy with the builds of a single project. Enter 0 to allow an unlimited number of builds to run simultaneously.*

Is there a way of doing this in TFS 2015?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the agent user capability to direct a specific build definition to a specific build agent resulting in one running build of that build definition

Comment: If the agent is building an other project, my current project is queued. while maby 3 other agents are idle. So your sollution results in a bad distribution of resources, and loss of the distributed build / failover

Comment: @NikoDierickx, you can choose other build agent in your build definition.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I don't understand how this would solve my issue?

Comment: @NikoDierickx, when create build definition, you need to select an agent queue for this build definition. You can deploy multiple agent queues or multiple build agents in one agent queue to achieve the requirement of simultaneous builds. You can assign one build agent to the specify build which you want to queue one by one.